# Docker: Error response from daemon: Pull access denied?

Tags: docker

docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 2350e0f1bf91, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.

I am logged into docker, and this repository does exist, not sure why I am getting this. 
I am using this command

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined 2350e0f1bf91
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the image on docker hub? It looks like an image id rather than an image name, which would work if that id was created locally. Note, this URL does not work for me as it should if that image existed on Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/2350e0f1bf91/